# React-toolbox date picker calendar dialog is moving DOM to the top

Tags: reactjs, typescript, datepicker, modal-dialog, react-toolbox

I have problem with react-toolbox's date picker and want to ask maybe someone had same problem. So, when I click on date picker input calendar dialog opens and moves background to top of the page. I want that modal would open on same position, where I am clicking.

I am using very simple date picker:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import DatePickerBase, { DatePickerProps } from 'react-toolbox/lib/date_picker/DatePicker';

export type DatePickerProps = {} & DatePickerBase;

export const DatePicker: React.SFC<DatePickerProps> = ({ ...props }) => {
  return <DatePickerBase {...props} />;
};
```

Maybe some had same problem with other react-toolbox dialogs? I would appreciate for any help.

Comment: Can you try to increase z-index value of your input.

Comment: Same result, nothing changes if I add z-index

Comment: I think there is a conflict between your css and components' css files. But I can't present my opinion without see the whole environment.